# Concatenate characters in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose we have a string "code". How would we concatenate any two characters? Say for example we need to concatenate last two characters,

`str.init.last + str.last` gives result as `201`. How would we get `de` instead?

Comment: That's not concatenating, that's simply dropping the first two chars. Is that all you want to do?

Comment: Taking last two characters was just an example.

Comment: Then specify what exactly you want to do. If you're talking about general string fiddling, you can use indexes into the string.

Comment: My question in general was if we can concatenate characters? One possible way as @Michal has shown and as you have suggested is to use indexes and convert the result into a String! Another way, similarly, could be `s"${str.init.last}${str.last}"`. I was wondering if characters can be concatenated without conversion to a String?

Comment: Concatenating two chars together doesn't produce another char, it produces a string.

Comment: Yes. But is this the only way to add say two characters? `val code = "code"; s"${code(1)}${code(3)}"`

Comment: It depends on what is your goal. Char is in general a number representing character in ASCII table. Adding two Char values is in fact adding numbers. If you wish to produce String, you cannot use addition. Another way is to call `.toString` method on each char before addition but it makes code less readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to make any combination of characters:

```
scala> val code = "code"
code: String = code

scala> s"${code(1)}${code(3)}"
res0: String = oe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"code".init.last.toString + "code".last.toString

val res7: String = de
```

(use `toString` first to convert `char` to `String` and then concatenate with `+`)